# Score is not counting correctly based on whether the correct answer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am pretty sure I have missed something simple, but Score is not counting correctly based on whether the correct answer has been selected. Its a multiple choice quiz. The code was written by someone else, so trying to figure this out alone! Any ideas?

---

```
var Question = function(Text){
  this.Question = Text;
  this.Answers = [];
  this.addAnswer = function(Answer, Correct){
    if(typeof Correct == 'undefined') Correct = false;
    else Correct = Correct == true;
    this.Answers.push({"Answer":Answer, "Correct":Correct});
  };
  this.checkAnswer = function(Index){
    if(typeof this.Answers[Index] == 'undefined') return false;
    return this.Answers[Index].Correct;
  };
};


var Questions = [];
var q;
var Score = 0;
var CurrentQuestion = -1;

var nextQuestion = function()
{
  ++CurrentQuestion;

  if(typeof Questions[CurrentQuestion] == 'undefined') return false;
  var Question = Questions[CurrentQuestion];

  $('#QuestionIndex').html(Numbers[CurrentQuestion]);
  $('#QuestionsRemaining').html((Questions.length-CurrentQuestion-1));
  $('#Question').html(Question.Question);
  $('#Answers').html('');


  for(var t in Question.Answers)
  {
    i = t;
    t = Question.Answers[t];
    var Div = $('<div class="answer"></div>');
    $(Div).append('<span class="radioContainer"><input type="radio" name="Answer" id="answer_'+ i +'"></span> ');
    $(Div).append($('<label for="answer_' + i + '" />').html(t.Answer));
    $('#Answers').append(Div);
  }

  $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
    $('.radioContainer').css('background-image', 'none');

    attr = $(this).attr('checked');
    if(typeof attr !== 'undefined' && attr !== false)
    {
   $(this).parent().css('background-image', 'url("http://dev.clickymedia.co.uk/fbart/wp-content/themes/artbook/img/tick.png")');
    }
  });

  return true;
}

//Returning false should stop the user from progressing to the next question.
var checkCurrentAnswer = function()
{
  if(typeof Questions[CurrentQuestion] == 'undefined') return false;
  var i = $('#Answers input:checked').parent().index();
  if(i < 0) return false;

  if(Questions[CurrentQuestion].checkAnswer(i) == true) Score++; 

  return true;
}

q = new Question("Which famous film star did Pop artist Andy Warhol make more portraits of than any other?");
q.addAnswer('Marilyn Monroe', true);
q.addAnswer('Sophia Loren');
q.addAnswer('Audrey Hepburn');
q.addAnswer('Doris Day');
Questions.push(q);

q = new Question("The Mona Lisa, Leonardo da Vinci's magnum opus, draws crowds into which famous European museum?");
q.addAnswer('The Mus&#233;e du Louvre, Paris', true);
q.addAnswer('The Tate Britain, London');
q.addAnswer('The National Gallery, Berlin');
q.addAnswer('The Uffizi Gallery, Florence');
Questions.push(q);

$(function(){
  nextQuestion();

  $('#nextQuestion').bind('click', function(){
    if(checkCurrentAnswer())
    {
      if(nextQuestion())
      {

      }else{ //End of examination! - Put your pens and pencils down.
        $('#QuestionBook .FinalLeft .Score').html(Score + '/' + Questions.length);

        $('#QuestionBook .FinalLeft .Message').html(Message);


        $('#QuestionBook .QuestionContainer, #QuestionBook .AnswersContainer').hide();
        $('#QuestionBook .FinalLeft, #QuestionBook .FinalRight').show();


      }
    }
  });
});
```

---

Comment: That's a **lot** of code and you've haven't given us a lot to go on. What do you mean "not counting correctly"? Steps to reproduce? What's incorrect about it? You could also try to remove as much of the code as possible, and come up with a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Score is incrementing on each question, whereas Score should only increment if the answer is correct.

Comment: There is not a lot I can skim out unfortunately as a lot of the functions are relative...Unfortunately, it wasn't my option to build it in this way as there is a lot simpler ways to do it I know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `checkCurrentAnswer` function is calculating the *wrong* index. Specifically, this line:

`var i = $('#Answers input:checked').parent().index();`

Your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="Answers">
  <div class="answer">
    <span class="radioContainer"><input type="radio" /></span>
    <label for="answer_0">The Musée du Louvre, Paris</label>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <span class="radioContainer"><input type="radio" /></span>
    <label for="answer_1">The Tate Britain, London</label>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Thus, `i` will ***always*** be `0`, since the parent of the `radio` input is always a `span`, which is always the *first* child (index `0`) of `answer`. You should count the `index` of the div with class `answer` instead.

To fix, it's simple, instead of using `parent()`, use `closest(".answer")`:

```
var i = $('#Answers input:checked').closest(".answer").index();
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to go through all that code. Well done. Whether your answer is correct or not I don't know, but well done on the effort. You've obviously put in more effort in your answer than OP with their question.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks! Sometimes it just one of those things where you have to put up a bit more code than normal as that isn't where I thought the issue lied! Thanks! :)